# How to get value from XML attribute using Sql:Variable in xquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

I want to get attribute value from XML using Xquery.

MY XML is

```
<Answers>
  <AnswerSet>
    <Answer questionId="NodeID">155</Answer>
    <Answer questionId="ParentNode" selectedValue="12">Product</Answer>
  </AnswerSet>
</Answers>
```

Below is my query.

```
DECLARE @Field Varchar(100)
DECLARE @Attribute VARCHAR(100)
SET @Field='ParentNode'
SET @Attribute = 'selectedValue'
```

```
SELECT ISNULL(PropertyXML.value('(/Answers/AnswerSet/Answer[@questionId=sql:variable("@Field")])[1]','varchar(max)'),'') ,
ISNULL(PropertyXML.value('(/Answers/AnswerSet/Answer[@questionId=sql:variable("@Field")]/sql:variable(@Attribute) )[1]','varchar(max)'),'') 
      FROM node 
     WHERE id=155
```

below line is working fine with sql:variable

```
ISNULL(PropertyXML.value('(/Answers/AnswerSet/Answer[@questionId=sql:variable("@Field")])[1]','varchar(max)'),'')
```

but I am getting error in below line..

```
ISNULL(PropertyXML.value('(/Answers/AnswerSet/Answer[@questionId=sql:variable("@Field")]/sql:variable(@Attribute) )[1]','varchar(max)'),'')
```

Any ideas on how to get provided `attribute(@Attribute)` value in result?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If you're using .value, has to be 2005+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
ISNULL(@Xml.value('(/Answers/AnswerSet/Answer[@questionId=sql:variable("@Field")]/@*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Attribute")])[1]','varchar(max)'),'')
```